# flutter_launcher_icon is not working properly

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, simulator

Today I got confused , just watch the screenshots, and please explain how to change the icons properly in flutter project,

For Android the dependency is working fine

But in iOs I am getting 2 icons just see the screenshots is there to solve this, I also want to change the black background colour to white just like other apps

My app name is **BT Video**

[image]

here is the another screenshot

[image]

here is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: badshai_trading_video
description: A video app for badshai trading students

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  provider: ^4.3.1
  uuid: ^2.2.0
  youtube_player_flutter: ^7.0.0+7
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  image: ^2.1.14
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.

  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#EB6F93"

flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/ypf.png
    - assets/icon/icon.png
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Is there anyone who can solve this ? why the icon is different ?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to using an icon image with a transparent background. While Android can deal with this, iOS can't, so you have to use an icon base image with a solid background (in your case white). If you want your Android icon to still have a transparent background, the `flutter_launcher_icons` package allows you to specify a separate `image_path_ios` or `image_path_android`.

Comment: My main problem is different icon, app icon changed for launcher, but when its launched and running in background then it shows different icon , I have mentioned the screenshot, Anyway thanks for suggestion

Comment: Yes, I understood that, I just thought iOS wasn't able to cope with it and while it worked on the launch screen, it didn't work in recents